# How to extract rows from R dataframe based on application of a function?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe like so:

```
  Items Years Counts  Blah   Bleh
1     A  1990   4565   ghf    kop
2     B  1990   4566   ecc    jde
3     A  1991   4567   sfg    iwx
4     D  1991   4568   ert    lwi
5     E  1991   4569   loi    xcz
6     B  1992   4570   kji    mnb
```

I want to be able to extract just Item, Years and Counts from the dataframe based on passing Items through a function. I dont want to return all columns For example:

```
function(word){length(word)>5)}
```

If the word in Item has a length longer than 5 I want to return the 3 columns for that value and leave out columns Blah and Bleh

So far I have tried

```
result <- sapply(df$Items, 1, function)
```

but it returns me an error that "dim(X) must have a positive length". After doing this step I would be unsure where to go as this would only return me the indices of rows where the function returns TRUE if I am correct.

I am struggling with R because I find it hard to stop thinking from a python perspective where I would have to loop through everything. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You might want to invest in learning a tabular data storage & manipulation interface like `data.table` or `dplyr`. Here is a `dplyr` solution that uses regular expressions to `select` the columns of interest:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df_foo = read.table(
  textConnection(
    "  Items Years Counts  Blah   Bleh
1     A  1990   4565   ghf    kop
2     B  1990   4566   ecc    jde
3     A  1991   4567   sfg    iwx
4     D  1991   4568   ert    lwi
5     E  1991   4569   loi    xcz
6     B  1992   4570   kji    mnb"
  ),
  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

df_foo %>% 
  select(matches("(.){5,}"))
```